# fbprophet export ds,yhat predictions to csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with the Prophet tutorial on [sub-daily data](https://facebookincubator.github.io/prophet/docs/non-daily_data.html). I'm also using the default [example_yosemite_temps.csv](https://github.com/facebookincubator/prophet/blob/master/examples/example_yosemite_temps.csv). I'm trying to export the ds and yhat prediction data to a CSV file. Below is what I have so far. For some reason only the header gets saves to the CSV.

How to get all the ds data into one column and all the yhat data into another column?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fbprophet import Prophet
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('example_yosemite_temps.csv')
m = Prophet(changepoint_prior_scale=0.01).fit(df)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=10, freq='H')
forecast = m.predict(future)

timestamp = forecast[['ds']]
tempFuture = forecast[['yhat']]

#print(timestamp)
#print(tempFuture)


rows = zip(timestamp,tempFuture)

with open('predict.csv', "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution with:

```
forecast.to_csv('PredictOutput.csv')
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html